# remove a div based on class and id

Tags: jquery, class, html, attr, removeclass

**i'm trying to remove a div based on the id and class but when executing i can only remove it by using an individual value from either the id or class but not both.**

EX:

```
<div id="69" class="form-loader">
    test 69
</div>
<div id="70" class="form-loader">
    test 70
</div>

<input type="text" value="69" id="loader-form-val"/>
<button class="form-delete-con">click</button>

$('.form-delete-con').live("click",function() { 
    var del = $('#loader-form-val').val();
    $('#'+del+' .form-loader').remove();
});
```

Comment: what jQuery version are you using?

Comment: If you want to select control using control's ID then class don't required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the extra white space in the string containing the class name, `.form-loader`

```
$('.form-delete-con').live("click",function() { 
    var del = $('#loader-form-val').val();
    $( '#' + del + '.form-loader').remove();
});              // ^ you had ' .form-loader'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r3vMW/1/

Comment: Hmm, why you use `'.form-loader'`? If you're targeting an `ID` element, believe me, you don't need additional selectors :) Also `live()` is long gone...

Answer (score 0):

`ID`s are **unique** therefore you don't need to bother with any `class` things

Also from jQuery `v.1.7` the `.live()` method is deprecated and it's substituted with `.on()`

**This will do the job:**

```
$(document).on("click", '.form-delete-con', function() { 
    var del = $('#loader-form-val').val();
    $("#"+ del).remove();
});
```